# Edit conflicted with a subsequent edit

Tags: support

I was on Stack Overflow, and I was editing a post of a user. I got this error:

[image]

I did my research before I posted this question. To get this error, your edit was entered before a user with 2k+ reputation was editing and his/her edit was somewhat similar.

[image]

What I found weird was that that user posted his edit about 20 minute later. Why is it like that?

Comment: *"and his/her edit was somewhat similar"* This is wrong. It doesn't matter if these edits are similar or not. *"What I found weird was that that user posted his edit about 20 minute later."* What is weird about that? Why should "time" be important here as long as your edit is still in review?

Comment: @tom If my edit was in the review process, why didn't the user see the edit?

Comment: He obviously either started editing before you or while you also edited and finished that later or he opended the question before you've finished the edit and didn't refresh it, so he still got the usual "edit" link.

Comment: I've encountered similar crossed time line issues before when editing. Something I have found useful when I see that my edit is going to take some time, and maybe research, to complete is I open the edit screen, copy the entire markdown text, paste it into my local text editor, and cancel the edit. I do all my editing locally, including my own spellchecker and proofreading. Then I reload the question, make sure it hasn't been edited while I was working, open the edit screen again, copy and paste my work over what's there, and submit my edit. Never had the issue since. Works for answers too. :D

Comment: When you get to 2k you can immediately get it edited but without gaining reputation.